# Is there a comma before "and why?" at the end of a question?

Tags: commas, independent-clauses, compound-sentences

If so, would I also put commas if a question ended with "why or why not?"

Ex: Are you going to bake cookies, and why, or why not?

Comment: I'd use a heavier-duty stop – a dash or ellipsis. A comma would be good to signify the lesser contrastive break in 'The question was whether we were going to bake cookies, and why or why not'.

Answer (score 0):

No. As the sentence is written, "why" and "why not" are independent clauses:

> Are you going to bake cookies, and why?
>
> Why not?

Normally, you would put a comma before *or* when it coordinates independent clauses.

However, [this guideline](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-or/) from Grammarly takes precedence:

> When just two short grammatical elements are coordinated with *or*, do
> not separate them with a comma.

Searching [the Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) bears out this usage:

> Are you going to bake cookies? Why or why not?

Comment: The Grammarly post does not appear to recognise the dual function that commas may perform: as an indicator of some grammatical point, or as indicators of pauses in the way the words would be spoken. I prefer "my martini stirred, not shaken" because when I ask for a martini I pause, very markedly before the word "not".  In the OP example, there is a really big pause after the question, even bigger than a mere comma could indicate. Hence the need for a period.

Comment: No. The _Grammarly_ advice comes in the section on lists, not the relevant 'Commas before “or” when beginning an [ie introducing a subsequent] independent clause' section.